# Is there a way to get ethereal email message ID in node.js through SendGrid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer

I'm currently using SendGrid as an email service in a web app, and I want to set up my dev environment to send emails to https://ethereal.email/ so I can make sure they look correct. The way I currently have it set up is I'll use `nodemailer.createTestAccount()` on startup, then log the credentials, then if I need to see the emails I have to manually go to the ethereal site to log in and view all the emails.

Since I'm using SendGrid to send the messages I can't just use `nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info)`, but I would really like to be able to just log the URL every time an email is sent in dev then I could just go directly to the message.

I've already tried printing the SendGrid response, as well as connecting via IMAP and loading the most recent message but neither of those contain the message ID anywhere that I can see.

Is there any way to get the message ID of an email sent to ethereal.email and construct a URL directly to the message?

My environment is node.js and I'm using @sendgrid/mail to send messages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The [Nodemailer documentation here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/testing/) suggests that you use ethereal.email as your SMTP settings in development. Then you can use `nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info)` to get the right URL.

You say you are using `@sendgrid/mail` to send messages, which won't respond with the URL as it is not sent out through the ethereal.email SMTP server. If you do want that URL, your best bet is to replace SendGrid in your development/test environment with ethereal.email.

You could do this by creating your own email sending objects with the same interface, one for  `@sendgrid/mail` and one for Nodemailer with ethereal.email credentials and load the object you want based on the environment.

For example:

```js
class SendGridEmail {
  constructor(sgApiKey) {
    // construct SG mail object
  }

  sendEmail(options) {
    // use SG mail object to send email
  }
}

class NodemailerEmail {
  constructor() {
  }

  sendEmail(options) {
  }
}

function getMailer() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    return new SendGridEmail(process.env.SG_API_KEY);
  } else {
    return new NodemailerEmail();
  }
}

// later

getMailer().sendEmail(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The thing is though that I'm using SendGrid's dynamic templates, so I don't have an email object I can use through nodemailer. I'm currently just replacing the receiver with an ethereal account but still using the SendGrid API.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the ethereal docs, the only way to get the URL of the message is to send the email through their SMTP server. So if you still need to send from SendGrid, you can't directly get that URL. If you want to set up more automated testing, I did see [this post on using ethereal and SendGrid with Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/05/24/full-testing-of-html-emails-using-ethereal-accounts/) to automatically test emails that might be of use.